# new samsung tab s3 connectivity

Tags: samsung

I've pre ordered one of the new samsung tab s3's. Since placing the order, I can't find any mention of a sim card slot or 4g.
Do any of you folks out there know if its wifi only, please?

Answer (score 2):

Totally depends on what you purchased.

This device follows the simple naming convention of many Samsung devices:

- Ending with 0 means WiFi
- Ending with 1 means 3G (mostly deprecated)
- Ending with 5/5Y means global LTE
- Ending with 7 means carrier-based LTE, with the carrier indicator letter right behind it (A for AT&T, T for T-Mobile, etc.)

Find a model number (SM-Txxx) from your order, then see the above rules to find out.